# spring rest service consume dynamic json field

Tags: json, spring, mongodb, rest, request

I got from javascript a json request for update mongoDb collection.
part of the json mapping to my java class(Person) but the inner json i mapped to JsonObject because dynamic field's names .
mapping the dyamic field's name to JsonObject not do the work.
how can i map the dyamic fields in Person class for keep it as is in mongo db

but the result is :

```
{ "person": "david",
  "family": "david family",
  "address":"david street", 
  "person_detail":{
                  "members":{}   **<=== should be list of key value**
                },
  "address_detail":{
                  "members":{}  **<=== should be list of key value**
                }
}
```

i expect that "person_detail" and "address_detail" will contains list of key value

I consume the  json by @requestBody.
how can i define the name of the class that should get the dynamic fields.

for example:

```
{ "person": "david",
  "family": "david family",
  "address":"david street", 
  "person_detail":{... collection of unknown pairs key value ....},
  "address_detail":{... collection of unknown pairs key value ....}
}

public Class Person{

   private String person;
   private String family;
   private JsonObject person_detail;
   private JsonObject address_detail;

   getter...

   setter...

}
```

my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/updatePerson"},method=RequestMethod.POST,consume="application/json")
public @ResponseBody ClientReturn clientReturn updatePerson(@RequestBody Person person) {

   ......

}
```

Comment: You are trying to map a list to a Json Object. You should be mapping it to JSONArray. If you were using Jackson, you could directly map it to a list.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for how to post list of keys values from client is to define the jsonObject
as `Map<String,Object>.`

> 

now it's work for me

```
public Class Person{

   private String person;
   private String family;
   private Map<String,Object> person_detail;
   private Map<String,Object> address_detail;

   getter...

   setter...

}
```